# want a simple code for the getting the state name and city name depend on the selection

Tags: java, android, procedural-programming

I am new to both android and java. I am developing a simple app which contain country , state and city which are selected by spinner. Now consider while am selecting the country(India) then i need to get only states of india. And then while selecting any state(Andhra pradesh) then the cities of A.P should be shown in the next spinner. Can any one suggest me with some sample code.

thanks in advance

Comment: This is a bad question for a lot of reasons. You need to be more specific, post the code you do have and give a more detailed explanation of what you want.

Comment: please dont expect us to do your home work. Try and start with it and in case you get any doubts someone here can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add this logic(for two spinners) to your code:

```
 public void onCreate() {
 ....
Country[] mCountries = ... ;
final Spinner spinner1 = ...;
final Spinner spinner2 = ...;

spinner1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(mCountries);
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener( new OnItemSelectedListener() {

void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Country country = (Country) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
    spinner2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(country.getStates());
 }
 void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    spinner2.setAdapter(null);
 }
});
```

....
}

Comment: Thanks, it helped me to start the code and i think this sample had helped me to get started. Thanks again.